# d3 elements within a group not being removed properly

Tags: d3.js

I have a table with filtered data that's working properly and now I'm trying to make a corresponding barchart. The barchart consists of a group for each bar, with two text elements and a rect inside of it. The exit selection successfully removes the g element but the internal rect and text somehow ends up in another g.

```
function updateSvg(data) {

parameters.svg = d3.select(".svg")
    .attr("height", data.length * parameters.barHeight)

var life_expectancy = d3.extent(data.map(getter('life_expectancy')));
  var min = life_expectancy[0];
  var max = life_expectancy[1];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, max])
.range([0, parameters.svgWidth])

// Data join.
var groups = parameters.svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)

// Enter. 
var groupsEnter = groups.enter().append("g").attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * parameters.barHeight + ")"; })

// Update.
var bars = groups.append("rect")
.attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.life_expectancy)})
.attr("height", parameters.barHeight - 1)

var labels = groups.append("text")
.attr("x", 20)
.attr("y", parameters.barHeight / 2)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function(d) { return d.name; })

var values = groups.append("text")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.life_expectancy) - 50; })
.attr("y", parameters.barHeight / 2)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function(d) { return d.life_expectancy})

// Exit.
groups.exit().remove()
}
```

Here's what I have working so far: http://chrisdaly.github.io/D3/World%20Countries%20Rank/table.html. If you untick all the continents except Oceania for example and inspect the bars, it shows a tonne of different rects etc hidden underneath the correct one. Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
groups.exit().remove()
```

On slider motion the values with in the country array will change but none of the g group DOM will get removed because the array still has the same number of array elements. So on that g group you go on appending rect and text.

```
groups.append("rect")
.attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.life_expectancy)})
.attr("height", parameters.barHeight - 1)
```

Now when you tick off Americas the g tag for USA will go which is what exit function does. Reason: your array is filtered has no record for USA.

But the g for Asia countries and others you append the text and rect again thus it keeps growing.

Best way out is when you update do this to remove all rect and text:

```
groups.selectAll("text").remove();
groups.selectAll("rect").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks Cyril that was well explained and worked perfectly.